# Building html tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The scenario is the following:
I call the buldMyStuff function to build images many times the following way. Wrapping the img into an "a" tag is not an option.

```
function buildMyStuff(item){
    var tag = <img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(' + item.Type + ',' + item.data+ ')" />';
    return tag;
}

function doClick(type,data){
    //do stuff
}
```

Lets assume that the item.type value is "type" and the item.data value is "data".
The problem with this that when I click the image it says type is not defined. Therefore (and I checked in the built html structure) the img eventually looks like this:

```
<img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(type,data)" />
```

What I need to achieve is:

```
 <img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick('type','data')" />
```

However as I am using the ' character to wrap the whole tag and the " character to wrap the attribute I cannot use anything else. Does someone know the solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'\'` to escape special characters.

`var tag = <img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(' + item.Type + ',' + item.data+ ')" />';`

=>

`var tag = '<img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(\'' + item.Type + '\',\'' + item.data+ '\')" />';`

Comment: Thanks Markus. I figured out after Matei Mihai's answer. He's solution was not correct, but yours is. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

this is invalid;

```
var tag = <img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(' + item.Type + ',' + item.data+ ')" />';
```

It should be

```
var tag = '<img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(\'' + item.Type + '\',\'' + item.data+ '\')" />';
```

Comment: But in that case the img will be:

<img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick("type","data")" />. That does not seem to be valid for me.

Comment: It looks like it, but in reality its "doClick('type','data')" the quotes are single but with a \ infront, this escapes the ' making it "doClick('type','data')"

Answer (score 1):

```
function buildMyStuff(item){ 
    var tag = '<img src="someimg.png" onclick="doClick(\'' + item.Type + '\',\'' + item.data+ '\')" />'; 
    return tag; 
}
```